# No migrations were found

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration

I am creating migrations in codeigniter. But I get an error saying that migrations are not found. I consulted official codeigniter docs. But in google, I couldn't find this error.

I created migrations folder and added following file.
001_Create_users.php

```
 <? php
 /**
  * Description of 001_create_users
  *
  * @author Isuru
  */
 class Migration_Create_users extends CI_Migration {

   public
   function up() {
     $this - > dbforge - > add_field('id');
     $this - > dbforge - > add_field(array(
       'id' => array(
         'type' => 'INT',
         'constraint' => 11,
         'unsigned' => TRUE,
         'auto_increment' => TRUE
       ),
       'email' => array(
         'type' => 'VARCHAR',
         'constraint' => '100',
       ),
       'password' => array(
         'type' => 'VARCHAR',
         'constraint' => '100',
       ),
       'name' => array(
         'type' => 'VARCHAR',
         'constraint' => '100',
       ),
     ));
     //$this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
     $this - > dbforge - > create_table('users');
   }

   public function down() {
     $this - > dbforge - > drop_table('users');
   }

 }
```

This is the migration.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable/Disable Migrations
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Migrations are disabled by default for security reasons.
| You should enable migrations whenever you intend to do a schema migration
| and disable it back when you're done.
|
*/
$config['migration_enabled'] = TRUE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Type
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Migration file names may be based on a sequential identifier or on
| a timestamp. Options are:
|
|   'sequential' = Default migration naming (001_add_blog.php)
|   'timestamp'  = Timestamp migration naming (20121031104401_add_blog.php)
|                  Use timestamp format YYYYMMDDHHIISS.
|
| If this configuration value is missing the Migration library defaults
| to 'sequential' for backward compatibility.
|
*/
$config['migration_type'] = 'timestamp';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migrations table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the name of the table that will store the current migrations state.
| When migrations runs it will store in a database table which migration
| level the system is at. It then compares the migration level in this
| table to the $config['migration_version'] if they are not the same it
| will migrate up. This must be set.
|
*/
$config['migration_table'] = 'migrations';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Auto Migrate To Latest
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If this is set to TRUE when you load the migrations class and have
| $config['migration_enabled'] set to TRUE the system will auto migrate
| to your latest migration (whatever $config['migration_version'] is
| set to). This way you do not have to call migrations anywhere else
| in your code to have the latest migration.
|
*/
$config['migration_auto_latest'] = TRUE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migrations version
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is used to set migration version that the file system should be on.
| If you run $this->migration->current() this is the version that schema will
| be upgraded / downgraded to.
|
*/
$config['migration_version'] = 1;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migrations Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Path to your migrations folder.
| Typically, it will be within your application path.
| Also, writing permission is required within the migrations path.
|
*/
$config['migration_path'] = APPPATH.'migrations/';
```

I tried to find a solution since yesterday, but I could not find a solution.

[image: Error]

Comment: Try with lower case in file name as in docs i.e. `001_create_users.php`.

Comment: http://s11.postimg.org/m8up28cmb/Untitled.png I tried it, but not working.

Comment: Which version of CI? Version 2 doesn't support timestamp type. And in tags you induced v.2 specifically. Maybe issue is  lying in version differences. If you are using v2 there is no variable as migration type, and if you are using v3 try to change to `$config['migration_type'] = 'sequential';`

Comment: @Tpojka I tried that one as well. http://s18.postimg.org/v15ythvuh/Untitled.png

Comment: Can you confirm CI version of your application?

Comment: @Tpojka CodeIgniter 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Change 'timestamp' to 'sequential' if you want to use '001'

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in 001_Create_users.php

```
<? php
```

and

```
- >
```

Answer (score 0):

For version 3.1.10 the correct path for migrations is /application/migrations.
hth

Comment: Isn't this just saying what Ledian said 3.5 years earlier?

Answer (score -1):

plese be sure that name of migration folder under applications to be migrations. 
Hope it helps!